# passing scope parameters to resolve function angularjs

Tags: angularjs, parameters, routes, resolve

I have a route provider with following configuration.

```
ocsApp.config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when('/userStat/:pageNo' ,
            {
                templateUrl:'userStats',
                controller:'userStatController',
                resolve: {
                    loadData: searchController.loadData
                }

            });            
    });
```

The loadData function i.e resolve method calls a service which needs around 6-7 parameters that I do not want to appear in route URL and all these are available in searchController scope. Is there a way i can pass those parameters in loadData function.

Code is like this.

```
     searchController.loadData=function($q,sessionFactory,$route){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
                sessionFactory.getSessions(siteId,startDate,endDate,pageNo,resultPerPage)
                success(function(data,status)
                {
                  deferred.resolve(data);
                 });

              return deferred.promise;
   };
```

is there a way to pass those parameters in loadData function.

Answer (score 0):

The "searchController" scope doesn't really exist in the context you're thinking of.

What you should do is abstract the parameters currently in the searchController scope into a service, put your parameters there, and inject that into your loaddata function. If binding is important, you will either have to manually update that service's parameters based on $watch or you can put an object of parameters from the service into the searchController scope and regular binding will work.